# How to use an Android Phone as a webcam with Mac Mini M1?

Tags: mac, mac-mini, facetime, android, webcam

I've recently bought a Mac Mini M1 and I realized I need a webcam for facetime, etc. I don't have an iPhone or other webcam to use and I need to use an android phone for now.

Can I use an android phone as a webcam with Mac Mini M1?

Comment: That might be best answered over on https://android.stackexchange.com. I would imagine if there is an Android app to do this they would know better than we would

Comment: As the question involves Apple hardware and software it is on-topic here. The question can be migrated if OP requests, but where a question is on-topic for two sites the default position is for it to remain.

Comment: there is EpocCam, not sure this works with Android though.